# Is there an easy way to see that $\phi =\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{\vec m \cdot \vec r}{r^3}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-moment, dipole

The scalar potential of an electric dipole is given by:
 $$\phi =\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{\vec p \cdot \vec r}{r^3}$$
The derivation of this is quick, however, is there an easy way to see that for a magnetic dipole we have:
$$\phi =\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{\vec m \cdot \vec r}{r^3}$$
by either analogy or via a similar derivation to that for the electric field?

Comment: Just consider the magnetic dipole to be from two magnetic charges. This 'trick' is fine if you only care about the field outside of an object (which is the case here).

Answer (score 1):

Since

$\nabla.B=0$ is true as long as we don't find monopoles

one can always define a vector potential for magnetic field whereas

$\nabla\times B=0$

is sometimes true ($J=0$ and $\frac {\partial E}{\partial t} = 0$ in the region of inerest) we can sometimes define scalar potential for the magnetic field.

If you go by ampere's law you will find that vector potential can be defined in terms of magnetic dipole as explained [here](http://www.physicspages.com/2013/04/11/magnetic-dipole/),

$\vec{A}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi r^2}m\times \hat{r}$

and from this relation you will get

$\vec {B}=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi r^3}[3(m.\hat{r})\hat{r}-m]$

and if you can define a magnetic scalar potential at this stage you will readily see that the magnetic scalar potential shown in your equation can give the correct magnetic field.

Hope this will help. For electric fields scalar potential can be directly evaluated from Gauss law but this is not possible here, and this may be the reason for such a complicated route.